# Finding out whether ObjectAtIndex returns an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to write some sort of catch statement around `([MyArray ObjectAtIndex:myindexpath.row])`so that I can run this without throwing an exception?

In other words, I want to write this sort of expression:

```
if ([MyArray ObjectAtIndex:myindexpath.row]) {

// do some stuff if the object is in the array

else {

// do some other stuff

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: use logic & maths.

```
if (index < myArray.count) {
    // ...
}
```